# Ansible User module - how to tell it to remove expired user accounts?

Tags: ansible, userdel

I am setting up user administration through Ansible for the first time. Can I use Ansible's user module to remove accounts that are past their expiration date? What conditional statement would I use?

Pardon my untested pseudocode, but I am looking for something like the following:

```
tasks:
 - name: remove expired users
   user: name=users.key state=absent force=yes
   when: expired  <----- what condition do I put here?
   with_dict: users
```

Comment: I answered assuming you meant expired accounts as in `useradd -e $expiry_date` rather than @tedder42's answer that thinks you meant that you had a list of users you maintain. Looking back at your question it's not overly clear which one you mean, could you clarify please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [shell module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html) to get back the list of users on each host that are expired (as in [`useradd -e $expire_time`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd)) and then pass that to the user module.

As an example we can set up some users that expire around now:

```sh
sudo useradd testexpires -e 2015-09-24
sudo useradd testexpires2 -e 2015-09-22
sudo useradd testexpires3 -e 2015-09-21
sudo useradd testexpires4 -e 2015-09-28
sudo useradd testexpires5 -e 2015-09-21
```

`sudo cat /etc/shadow` then shows:

```sh
...
testexpires:!:16701:0:99999:7::16702:
testexpires2:!:16701:0:99999:7::16700:
testexpires3:!:16701:0:99999:7::16699:
testexpires4:!:16701:0:99999:7::16706:
testexpires5:!:16701:0:99999:7::16699:
```

We can then check whether that epoch date in the 8th column is older than today by using this reasonably horribly shell one liner:

```sh
sudo cat /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f1,8 | awk -F: '{if($2<{{ epoch_day }} && $2 != ""){print $0}}' | cut -d: -f1
```

We can easily get the epoch date using Ansible's built in [`ansible_date_time`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts) variable which gives us the epoch time in seconds and dividing through using [Jinja's math filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#math):

```
epoch_day  : "{{ ansible_date_time.epoch | int / 86400 | round() }}"
```

Putting this together (and escaping out the quotes in the awk) gives us a playbook that if you wanted to run it on localhost would look something like this:

```
- hosts        : localhost
  connection   : local
  gather_facts : yes
  vars  :
    epoch_day  : "{{ ansible_date_time.epoch | int / 86400 | round() }}"
  tasks :    
    - name  : debug epoch day
      debug : var=epoch_day

    - name         : get users expired before today
      shell        : "cat /etc/shadow | cut -d: -f1,8 | awk -F: '{if($2<{{ epoch_day }} && $2 != \"\"){print $0}}' | cut -d: -f1"
      changed_when : False
      register     : expired_users

    - name  : debug expired_users
      debug : var=expired_users.stdout_lines

    - name : remove expired users
      user :
        name  : "{{ item }}"
        state : absent
        force : yes
      with_items : expired_users.stdout_lines
```

Running this playbook when you don't have any expired users will make Ansible skip the last task because you don't have any items to pass to the task.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there was a module parameter that would simply compare current date with users' expiry dates. As it is, I'll need to use your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I simply maintain two lists of users: "current" and "former". Don't delete a user, move it from one list to the other.

```
tasks:
 - name: ensure users
   user: name=item.key state=present force=yes
   with_dict: current_users

tasks:
 - name: remove expired users
   user: name=item.key state=absent force=yes
   with_dict: former_users
```

If you wish to search for user accounts you'll need to script it, remove system accounts, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am planning to maintain one list, with a creation and expiration date for each user.